# Arduino used as a multi-sensor controller, then sending results to a laptop to post on a web page

Tags: sensors, datalogging

We are a non-profit group, we run a salmon rearing pond on Lake Michigan. We are upgrading our equipment that is over 50 years old with monitoring sensors.

We are adding 9 temperature, 5 oxygen, 2 air temperature, and several voltage and current sensors, hooked up to an Arduino. We need to have the results sent to a laptop to post them on a web page, and record values in a log.

We also want to do some simple calculations so that when a value drops below a preset level an output (valve) is activated until the level is corrected. We also want a built-in timer to control different equipment.

The high-voltage part (240 V, 480 V) is my area of expertise. Any help or ideas?

Comment: yes .. start with one sensor

Comment: Instead of developing your own solution from scratch (which would be a learning experience that might or might not be enjoyable), you might also want to look at a project like [Home Assistant](https://www.home-assistant.io/).

Answer (score 2):

Tackle this project as any other, divide and conquer.

First learn how to provide a static web site with the Arduino. There are multiple options, so please do your research and follow the inevitable tutorials. Experiment with a few to choose the best alternative for your case.

Then add dynamic values, for example with a simple time-controlled algorithm that alters a value. You can mock up monitored values, it does not matter. Make sure the dynamic web site works as you wish. You have also multiple options here.

Then add a first sensor to measure. First use the raw value to make sure you have the correct results. Only if you succeed, continue to scale the raw value to the physical value you want to use.

Finally extend with the next sensors, one after the other, in the same manner.

Doing "baby steps" helps you identify gaps in your knowledge (fill them) and avoids complex debugging. Never try to develop all at once. To accelerate the development, you can distribute the separate independent steps to multiple developers. This is how professionals do it, and there is no reason why it will not work for you.